# Installing GDAL on Linux Ubuntu Server

Tags: gdal, installation, linux, apt-get

`apt-get install python-gdal` installs version 1.6.0 and this is already installed. I would like to install the 1.9.0 version.

Do I have to de-install 1.6.0 first and then compile manually or is there an `apt-get` package that I have missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get 1.9 from Ubuntugis (see https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable).

See http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries for other sources of binaries.

Failing all else you can build 1.9 from the sources (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildHints)

Answer (score 61):

**Note:** this is an answer for an older version of GDAL, and [there are newer versions available](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/) (including [*current*](http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/CURRENT/)) that can be compiled similar to this answer. Just replace the version numbers in the commands below.

---

Build from source, with Python bindings:

```sh
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-all-dev
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.0/gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz
tar xvfz gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.0.0
./configure --with-python
make
sudo make install
```

In addition, some Linux distributions require the shared library cache to be updated after install:

```sh
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Thanks Mike is was very helpful, your description how on to build up gdal from the source.

Comment: @Rengifo Please upvote useful answers. You may leave comments but upvoting is even more important.

Comment: After 2 days unable to get gdal functioning in Ubuntu, finding this comment was /very/ helpful!  One minor note though is that the rest of the GIS stack installs into /usr/local/bin and this seems to install into /usr/bin/

Comment: I had trouble installing from the repository. This took awhile to execute but it worked.

Comment: For what it is worth, this was one of the quickest/easiest install-from-source packages I've had dealt with in a while. Recommend going this route!

Comment: For future users: the folder structure changed a little bit. In order to download the latest stable version, the `wget` command would look as follows:  `wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.11.1/gdal-1.11.1.tar.gz`.

Comment: It's better to use [checkinfo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) instead of make install, in case you ever wanted to uninstall it. Simple make uninstall didn't work for GDAL installed this way.

Comment: What is required after these steps to use gdal from python? I get a module not found when trying to import assuming I need to make python aware of it

Comment: @pksorensen ask in a different question with your details, since the above steps should install it for Python

Comment: thanks. The confirmation was enough for me to solve my problem.

Comment: I get: `make: *** No rule to make target "config.status", needed by "GDALmake.opt".  Stop.`. I have make installed

Comment: This worked perfect for Gdal 2.4 as well

Answer (score 8):

In case the question asked was still relevant, I managed to install `Python-Gdal` on `Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)` simply using:

`apt-get install python-gdal`

Comment: Your answer just made my day. I had been going by Mike's still good answer but I encountered some crazy error when installing on the third machine. But when running this it went smoothly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You can get 1.9 from Ubuntugis (see https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable) as you're running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.  1.9 was built for Lucid for the OSGEO Live DVD and should be available for other Ubuntu versions soon (ish). Source: [some email traffic](http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/ubuntu/2012-February/000470.html) on the UbuntuGIS mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use with my Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```