# How to install stable GDAL on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: gdal

I am trying to install the stable ubuntu package from here https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ppa/+packages on my ubuntu 11.10 server

I have added the ubuntugis stable repository to server's list of software sources with these commands

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
```

But, `apt-get install libgdal1-1.8.0` command fails to find the package. Is the ubuntu 11.10 server not supported? I am newbie with this, so i am not sure if the missing oneric (ubuntu 11.10) entries is a sign that it is supported.

Comment: It looks like they support Natty, Maverick, Lucid, Karmic, Jaunty, Intrepid, and Hardy, but not Oneiric. In doubt, install from source http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21739/1872

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GDAL 1.9 is available for Oneiric 11.10 in ubuntugis unstable. https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable?field.series_filter=oneiric

According to this [email exchange](http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/ubuntu/2012-February/000470.html) from 2 Feb 2012:

> stable PPA is only upgraded twice a year, or for security releases. It does not contain any oneiric packages because oneiric is new. and we do not push the packages since we don't know if they are *stable* since no user tested them at the moment of the upgrade. In april, the unstable-oneiric packages will be moved to stable.

Comment: @Jan You might want to ask this on a separate thread :) That way others can learn from your problem.

Answer (score 2):

An addendum to what Luke wrote above:

- First thing you should ask yourself is whether you really need the
  latest version of gdal on your server. Sticking to the one provided
  in ubuntu has the advantage that security updates will be provided,
  and no other updates which may break your application. You will be
  less sure of that when using the ubuntugis-stable or
  ubuntugis-unstable repository.
- If you *really* need the latest version
  of gdal, I would download the packages from the ubuntugis-unstable
  repository as Luke pointed out, but I would not keep that repository
  in your sources list afterwards.