# Why can't I install python-qgis on Ubuntu 12?

Tags: qgis, python, installation, ubuntu

I am with ubuntu 12 and Qgis 1.8. I have installed QGIS and grass plugin but I can't install python plugin. How to install python plugin with dependeny in Ubuntu?

```
~$ sudo apt-get install python-qgis
[sudo] password for sugandha: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-qgis : Depends: python-qt4 (>= 4.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I think this might be because not all of the packages requested are present in the repository. It's happened to me using the package manager, if you wait a day and then try again you might have better luck. N.

Comment: @nhopton its 4th day :( already tried installing dependency it asks for another dependency in chain...

Comment: Then I'm stuck I'm afraid. If you try installing QGIS using the package manager do you get the 'Partial Download' warning?

Comment: Hi, are you using the ubuntugis repository? check here for a similar problem and how to add a new repository: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33252/qgis-how-to-change-gdal-version/33267#comment44703_33267

Comment: just a thought: have you tried <code>sudo apt-get build-dep python-qgis</code>  ???

Comment: If you try to install python-qgis by itself, you'll run into a weird libcurl dependency, where the version of libcurl4 the rest of your system depends on has to be uninstalled and a new version installed. Apparently, this has to do with licensing issues. The best way to get python-qgis is to install QGIS from the QGIS repos (as RK suggests below), because they include versions of all the required libraries that are compiled against the version of libcurl4 used in Ubuntu. Welcome to dependency hell.

Answer (score 1):

Which repository are you using? You might want to add the following to you /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly precise main
```

After that, update your system

```
apt-get update
```

Next, add the qgis public key to our package manager's key ring

```
gpg –keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com –recv 1F9ADD375CA44993
gpg –export –armor 1F9ADD375CA44993 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then try installing again.

```
sudo apt-get install python-qgis
```

source: http://blog.gambliser.com/2012/06/how-to-install-quantum-gis-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/