# Convert multiple TIFFs into one?

Tags: geoserver, data, wms, geotiff-tiff, tiles

I have downloaded the Blue Marble dataset, and it consists of eight GeoTIFF images, labeled like this:
A1 B1 C1 D1

A2 B2 C2 D2

I would like to use these tiles for GeoServer to be served as WMS. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use multiple images as data source.

1) Can this be somehow done in GeoServer?

2) If not, what tool can be used to merge such images into single huge GeoTIFF file? IrfanView is out of question, it freezes trying to open a single image...

Comment: GDAL_Merge, GDALWArp (may be with QGIS interface), SAGA Raster modules, gvSIG, ArcGIS and probably more soft can do that. Process is call merge or mosaic.

Comment: Luckily the @iant's link was grabbed by the Wayback Machine. Thanks Internet Archive! https://web.archive.org/web/20121130223652/http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/bluemarble/bluemarble.html

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Here you are making a comment in the area reserved for direct answers to the original question.  Normally such "answers" are deleted, but in this instance I will convert it to a comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a [tutorial](http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/bluemarble/bluemarble.html) on exactly this problem that you may find helpful.

Basically it boils down to using gdal_translate, gdal_merge and gdal_retile so you will need to have installed GDAL. Either use [apt-get install gdal](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22726/how-to-install-stable-gdal-on-ubuntu-11-10) or the [osgeo4w installer](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)

Comment: It seems, from a comment on this question, and a quick test, that the link to your tutorial is broken.