# Repairing broken GDAL and PROJ.4 on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, ogr2ogr, ubuntu, proj

I solved the library problem, but others remain, only vaguely related to that of PROJ.4 libraries are not loaded. I asked a [follow-up question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/157406/12768) for these.

My GDAL package and PROJ.4 library are damaged, which causes errors while trying to reproject files (see old question below). I don't know whether this problem started while I mistakenly installed another instance of GDAL or before; however, I've uninstalled it and reinstalled QGIS and the problem remains.

After each reinstall, QGIS has the same plugins as before, so the part causing the errors is left untouched by the install/uninstall process.

What have I tried:

- `sudo apt-get remove build-essential python-all-dev` and `sudo apt-get remove gdal-bin` to purge the manually installed GDAL
- (un)install of QGIS with Ubuntu Software Center
- `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`
- `dpkg -l | grep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs dpkg --purge` and `dpkg --list | grep "^rc" | cut -d " " -f 3 | xargs sudo dpkg --purge` to purge the configuration files

Still no luck. I've found [something that seemed related](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/How-to-quot-uninstall-purge-quot-QGIS-in-Windows-td4644899.html), but that's for Windows, not for my Ubuntu 14.04. What else (and how) should I purge before next install of QGIS?

---

The original question:

I try to reproject some shapefiles with ogr2ogr. However, I always get the following error:

```
ERROR 6: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (libproj.so), creation of
OGRCoordinateTransformation failed.
Failed to create coordinate transformation between the
following coordinate systems.  This may be because they
are not transformable, or because projection services
(PROJ.4 DLL/.so) could not be loaded.
```

I tested this with various transformations, including such basic combinations as from WGS84 (EPSG:4326) to UTM (EPSG:3857), and this error occurs all the time.

The problem might be caused by the fact that although I have GDAL with my QGIS (2.10), I mistakenly installed it once more (from the source, doing it as [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21739/12768) suggested).

After facing this problem a few times, I tried to uninstall the new GDAL instance (`sudo apt-get remove build-essential python-all-dev` and `sudo apt-get remove gdal-bin` - not sure whether it is cleanly removed or not).

In `/USR/LIB/` I have `libproj.so.0` and `libproj.so.0.7.0`, not `libproj.so`. I can't see it even with hidden files shown. However, when I try `ln -s libproj.so.0.7.0 libproj.so` (or the same with `sudo`), it complains that `libproj.so` already exists.

Comment: It might help to remove and reinstall qgis as well.

Comment: @AndreJ: reinstalled and nothing changed. However, the associated files seem untouched (I have the same plugins as before QGIS reinstall etc.), so I'll try to remove it completely now.

Comment: I think you should edit the title and tags. Your issue is an installation problem and you might want to ask how to correct a broken installation.

Comment: @user30184: editted, as you suggested.

Comment: You have not mentioned from which repository you installed QGIS and GDAL. I usually use ubuntugis unstable, but that has not yet QGIS 2.10 (if you need that). The official Ubuntu GIS software is mostly outdated. Installing from different sources will surely lead to trouble.

Comment: That error message does seem to indicate that libproj isn't being loaded. Although the packages should have done it already, have you run `sudo ldconfig`? Also, does the output of `ldd ogrinfo` (you may have to give the full path for ogrinfo) show libproj.so and is it in the directory you expected (/usr/lib)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After several wrong ways, including multiple reinstall of `libproj0` package and even installing QGIS from sources different from the Ubuntu Software Center default (I think it's from the official QGIS repository - `http://qgis.org/debian trusty main`), I understood how to apply advice by @EvilGenius: `ldd ogrinfo` didn't show `libproj` no matter how many times I used `sudo ldconfig`, until I typed:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

Since then, the library is read normally.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. If you could help me here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67133013/4300670

Comment: @AlitonOliveira: unfortunately, I left the work with QGIS five years ago, so I don't know.

Answer (score 15):

In https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158457/gdal2tiles-how-to-make-filenames-of-tiles-to-represent-xyz-coordinates, somebody mentions doing:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libproj.so.0 /usr/lib/libproj.so
```

Which absolutely fixed the same error (ERROR 6: Unable to load PROJ.4 library (libproj.so)) for me.

---

On the x86_64 architecture you may need to use this variation:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libproj.so.0 /usr/lib/libproj.so
```

Comment: This solved it for me, And I was doing my head in trying to find it by the filename in the error, while its called libproj.so.0

Comment: I needed to symlink both `libproj` and `gdal` and with different numbers — i.e. `ln -s /usr/lib/libproj.so.15 /usr/lib/libproj.so; ln -s /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20 /usr/lib/libgdal.so` but working for me now, thanks for the steer!

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libproj-dev
```

It solved the same error for me when using gdal_translate for extracting bands from an hdf image.

Answer (score 0):

use ***--with-static-proj*** when compiling gdal libraries.

Comment: It would be useful to include a bit of an explanation along with your answer

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing proj-devel in the case of Fedora. On Ubuntu this may have a different name such as libproj-dev