# How to re-compile ogrinfo against gdal used by QGIS?

Tags: gdal, ogr, installation, ogr2ogr, ubuntu

I just solved [Repairing broken GDAL and PROJ.4 on Ubuntu?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/157059/12768) which was blocking use of `ogrinfo` and `ogr2ogr`, only to find that these utilities are garbled in one more way: whenever I run any of these, I get following error (this is for `ogrinfo`, for `ogr2ogr` it's analogical):

```
ERROR 1: ogrinfo was compiled against GDAL 1.9 but current library version is 1.10
```

I think I understand the cause: I mistakenly installed GDAL 1.9 manually through `make-install` as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21739/12768); `make-uninstall` is not possible for it. `Ogrinfo` was compiled to this version of GDAL and forgot about version 1.10 shipped with my QGIS (2.10). But I'm stuck here, with no idea how to re-compile `ogr` against the right version of GDAL.

What I tried:

- reinstall QGIS (with `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` to clean the dependencies after uninstall)
- trash `ogrinfo`, `ogr2ogr` and even whole `GDAL-1.9` directory; then I have recovered the `ogr` files but not gdal 1.9, though I can do it any time
- few more options like `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Perhaps I could cleanly purge and install the ogr package if I knew it's exact name. Or do I need to purge the old version completely and then somehow (how?) tell the QGIS installer to install ogr as well?

---

I searched for all the `gdal` files on my computer and found that I have files for `gdal-1.10` in `/usr/bin/` and those for `1.9` in `/usr/local/bin/`. I manually deleted all the 1.9 files - @evilGenius pointed to this. Now there's just the last step: to point the system to the correct path to the binaries. As `/usr/bin/ogrinfo` it works perfectly.

Comment: All of the OGR tools are actually a part of the GDAL package, so if you (re)install the proper one you should get them. I believe that's what @AndreJ is getting at as well. It's possible that you manually installed GDAL to a different prefix than where QGIS puts it (ie. /usr vs. /usr/local). If that's the case, you may have to manually purge your compiled version.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220186/how-can-i-get-self-compiled-packages-to-play-nice-with-packages-managers-e-g-a and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-should-i-put-software-i-compile-myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get GDAL 1.10 from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.10.1/ and compile it the same way as you did with 1.9.

BTW, GDAL 1.11.2 is the current stable version, and installing QGIS on a vanilla lubuntu 15.04 includes that GDAL version. So if you remove (delete the self-compilation and `sudo apt-get purge` the packages) all GDAL and QGIS stuff, then reinstall QGIS 2.10, you should have it too.

Alternatively, http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gdal-bin should give you the right GDAL package. I guess you removed the wrong (i.e. working) installation with `sudo apt-get remove gdal-bin`.

Comment: My problem is not how to find the right version, but how to make the system find it. I don't want to install anything new via make install; that would be just staying in a trap of apps almost impossible to uninstall.

Comment: If you delete the self-compilation and add the official package, it should run without manual adjustment.