# Why the integration of pygeoapi "OGC API Features" in QGIS 3.14 is not working?

Tags: qgis, ogc, ogc-api

I'm using [pygeoapi](https://pygeoapi.io/) as my server, and I'm having troubles with the connection of QGIS (3.14.0-Pi). I can see the list of layers available when I connect with my server from QGIS, but when I add to the project the layer is empty (no data, no geometry) and it gives me the follow warning.

```
2020-08-11T08:58:48     WARNING    Cannot create temporary SpatiaLite cache.: GDALCreate() failed: OGR was built without libspatialite support
             ... sorry, creating/writing any SpatiaLite DB is unsupported
```

I don't understand if this is a problem in pygeoapi or QGIS. The only mention between pygeoapi and libspatialite is in the [pygeoapi documentation](https://docs.pygeoapi.io/en/latest/development.html), but this is a configuration for OSX and my server is in Linux Machine, and I don't know how to translate this.

So basically, if anyone have experience with pygeoapi, and the integration with QGIS I will love to hear

Comment: Does your OGC API Features server support GeoJSON output? are you loading the service as a vector/geojson layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something with your GDAL build. The question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168921 seems to be a similar problem and might solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and thank you for pygeoapi) I found that but I was sceptical because of the date and the fact that “OGC API Features” are still very recent in QGIS. But I will check that, because now it looks like a problem in QGIS (gdal) and not with pygeoapi.

Comment: This was the problem, now it works just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the following?

[image]

On my side, the layer display.

The WFS approach also works on my QGIS (3.14 Ubuntu 64 bits) e.g

[image]

Second approach is better as it will take care of paging whereas the first solution need to care about limit of features you retrieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried that now and it worked! I was just trying to add the data using the WFS protocol of QGIS, and that finds the collections but does not add the data.

Comment: OAPI features is not WFS protocol, it is a whole new architecture

Comment: The second solution was the one I did and found myself with an empty table and that warning, now I tried with: “https://demo.pygeoapi.io/master/” and I have the same problem, Can you see the data in Attribute table or queried when you add the WFS3?

Comment: Yes, got the representation and the records with their attributes in the table. That's why @tomkralidis answered you have an issue with your GDAL. I do not reproduce your issue as my GDAL is "fine"