# Problem with import CSV to CartoDB

Tags: carto, import

I have installed CartoDB on my local machine and I can't upload data via import.

Data to upload

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name
48.1,0.25,"First point"
49.2,1.1,"Second point"
47.5,0.75,"Third point"
```

I am receiving the error:

```
true: Importing data from /tmp/imports/20151014-21811-1binquy/123.csv
true: File-based import load
true: Detected encoding ISO-8859-1
true: Using database connection with {:adapter=>"postgres", :encoding=>"unicode", :host=>"localhost", :port=>5432, :database=>"cartodb_dev_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090_db", :username=>"postgres", :conn_validator_timeout=>900, :pool=>50, :user=>"development_cartodb_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090"}
false: ogr2ogr call:            OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO PG_USE_COPY=YES PGCLIENTENCODING=ISO-8859-1   -f PostgreSQL   PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=development_cartodb_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090 dbname=cartodb_dev_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090_db password=53e933beffd3aef71b99afe6586c9afca5804943development_cartodb_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090"  -lco DIM=2 -lco PRECISION=NO /tmp/imports/20151014-21811-1binquy/123.csv  -nln cdb_importer.importer_e2b0c8ba726711e59e5400505681560b -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI  
true: ogr2ogr output:          sh: -f: command not found

true: ogr2ogr exit code:       32512
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: Ogr2ogr FAILED!
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: ogr2ogr.exit_code = 32512
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: ogr2ogr.command = OSM_USE_CUSTOM_INDEXING=NO PG_USE_COPY=YES PGCLIENTENCODING=ISO-8859-1   -f PostgreSQL   PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user=development_cartodb_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090 dbname=cartodb_dev_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090_db password=53e933beffd3aef71b99afe6586c9afca5804943development_cartodb_user_f4f00efc-27e9-4321-af96-8bbb73245090"  -lco DIM=2 -lco PRECISION=NO /tmp/imports/20151014-21811-1binquy/123.csv  -nln cdb_importer.importer_e2b0c8ba726711e59e5400505681560b -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI  
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: ogr2ogr.command_output = sh: -f: command not found

true: Errored importing data from /tmp/imports/20151014-21811-1binquy/123.csv:
===LOG END===
true: ----------------------------------------------------
false: ["/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/loader.rb:335:in `check_for_import_errors'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/loader.rb:268:in `run_ogr2ogr'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/loader.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/cartodb/stats/aggregator.rb:97:in `method_missing'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/loader.rb:62:in `block in run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/cartodb/stats/aggregator.rb:97:in `method_missing'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/loader.rb:52:in `run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:222:in `file_based_loader_run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:177:in `import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:327:in `execute_import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:256:in `block (3 levels) in single_resource_import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:249:in `each'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:249:in `each_with_index'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:249:in `block (2 levels) in single_resource_import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/cartodb/stats/aggregator.rb:97:in `method_missing'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:248:in `block in single_resource_import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/cartodb/stats/aggregator.rb:97:in `method_missing'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:226:in `single_resource_import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:95:in `run_import'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:88:in `block in run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/cartodb/stats/aggregator.rb:97:in `method_missing'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/services/importer/lib/importer/runner.rb:87:in `run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/app/connectors/importer.rb:39:in `run'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/app/models/data_import.rb:618:in `new_importer'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/app/models/data_import.rb:354:in `dispatch'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/app/models/data_import.rb:163:in `run_import!'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/resque/importer_jobs.rb:9:in `block in perform'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/resque/base_job.rb:21:in `call'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/resque/base_job.rb:21:in `run_action'", "/opt/openmap/carto/cartodb/lib/resque/importer_jobs.rb:9:in `perform'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/job.rb:240:in `block (3 levels) in perform'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-metrics-0.1.1/lib/resque/metrics.rb:353:in `around_perform_metrics'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/job.rb:239:in `block (2 levels) in perform'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/job.rb:247:in `call'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/job.rb:247:in `perform'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:250:in `perform'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:189:in `block in work'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:166:in `loop'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/worker.rb:166:in `work'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/resque-1.25.2/lib/resque/tasks.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'", "/usr/local/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'"]
true: ----------------------------------------------------
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: Proceeding to register
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: After importer run
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: After dispatch
2015-10-14 11:37:03 UTC: ERROR!

===LOG END===
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't find any solution you can do this by root

```
cd /usr/local/bin
mv ogr2ogr ogr2ogr2
vi ogr2ogr
#!/bin/bash
ogr2ogr2 "$@"
```

It is a very bad idea... but its work...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was installing GDAL as detailed in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21739/63143) then changed "which ogr2ogr2" under app_config.yml to read "which ogr2ogr"